# Implementing a Scheme interpreter that can handle if and cond

Tags: scheme, interpreter

------------------------------------update-------------------------------------

I can make it work pretty well with this.

```
(define (handle-cond exp env)
(if (null? exp) (newline) 
  (if (eq? (caar exp) 'else) (my-eval (cadar exp) env) 
  (if (my-eval (caar exp) env) (my-eval (cadar exp) env) (my-eval (cons 'cond (cdr exp)) env)))))
```

Only difference between this and the system's cond is that when no condition is true,
it'll print a #void, I don't quite understand why, but other than this, it works fine.
Thank you all for answering.

Comment: @APerson Your edit only made this question less clear (e.g. expanding unquoted Scheme keywords into the closest English match - instead of quoting them).

Comment: @AndrewMedico How so? I didn't touch the code.

Comment: I mean in the text. "here consider if is implemented" should be something like "Assume `if` is implemented" (meaning `if` is syntax defined by the language and does not need to be defined as part of the solution). Likewise, in "once it encounter a cond statement" - `cond` is a specific keyword. Replacing it with the generic "conditional" was not appropriate.

Comment: The first `if`. What is it you are checking for an empty value?

Comment: I did something like recursion, check the first condition, if it's not true, just go on and look at the next condition, if none is true, it would go to a '(), so I have to deal with null too.@Sylwester

Comment: #void is the return value of `(newline)` which you call when `exp` is `null?` (all clauses are false). In R6RS the return value of a `cond` expression if all values are false is unspecified.

Comment: I'm using R5RS, and what should I do if I want it to do nothing, just like the scheme system itself?@Rptx

Answer (score 1):

You would have to turn the `cond` statement, into a series of nested `if`s. So suppose that each `cond` clause is something like this:

```
(cond
  (<expr1> <expr2>)
  (<expr3> <expr4>)
  (else <expr5>))
```

; This would become:

```
(if <expr1> 
    <expr2>
    (if <expr3>
        <expr4>
        <expr5>))
```

Comment: I did something like recursion, check the first condition, if it's not true, just go on and look at the next condition, if none is true, it would go to a '(), so I have to deal with null too.